# Can't perform a React state update on an` unmounted` component

Tags: reactjs

is it a serious problem?

i'm seeing following error when i try to move to another page via `<link>` in react-router

```
warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
 This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
            at Timer
```

here is Timer useeffect

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const current = interval.current;
    startTimer()
    return () => {
      clearInterval(current)
    }
  })
```

here is Interval, it takes a date then computes the difference and then returns it to useState hook

```
  let interval = useRef();
  const startTimer = () => {
    const countdownDate = new Date(`${data.remainTimeRanking}`).getTime()
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      const now = new Date().getTime()
      const distance = countdownDate - now;
      const days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      const hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (1000 * 60 * 60)))
      const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      const seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(interval.current)
      } else {
        setTimerDays(days)
        setTimerHours(hours)
        setTimerMinutes(minutes);
        setTimerSeconds(seconds)
      }
    }, 1000);
  };
```

Comment: it would be useful for people provide you better assistance if you display how you set `interval`, and what value you pass to `interval.current`

Comment: I added interval :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not overwrite your ref variable with another value. once you instantiate a ref variable, what you desire to anchor should be stored at `current` attribute.

Hence, you need to associate `setInterval` return value to `current` attribute from `interval`:

```
interval.current = setInterval(() => {
  const now = new Date().getTime()
  const distance = countdownDate - now;
  const days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  const hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (1000 * 60 * 60)))
  const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  const seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(interval.current)
  } else {
    setTimerDays(days)
    setTimerHours(hours)
    setTimerMinutes(minutes);
    setTimerSeconds(seconds)
  }
}, 1000);
```

at useEffect just pass `interval.current` directly as well, and pass `[]` as second argument to execute your `useEffect` only on mount:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    startTimer()
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval.current)
    }
  }, [])
```